# How to change the colour of ReactSelect component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

Hello I am using the React select component, `import ReactSelect, {ValueType} from 'react-select';`

Currently my component looks like this:
[image]

This is the code for it:

```
 <div>
                <ReactSelect
                         className='react-select react-select-top'
                         classNamePrefix='react-select'
                         id='displayLanguage'
                         menuIsOpen={this.state.openMenu}
                         menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                         options={timeOptions}
                         clearable={false}
                         onChange={this.onChange}
                         onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                         value={this.state.selectedOption}
                         onMenuClose={this.handleMenuClose}
                         onMenuOpen={this.handleMenuOpen}
                         aria-labelledby='changeInterfaceLanguageLabel'
                         isDisabled={false}
                    />
            </div>
```

I want to change the colour of it to grey to look more like this but I am not sure how to:
[image]

Comment: This seems like relevant documentation: https://react-select.com/styles

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,
found here https://react-select.com/styles

```
const customStyles = {
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    borderBottom: '1px dotted pink',
    color: grey,
    padding: 20,
  }),
  control: () => ({
    // none of react-select's styles are passed to <Control />
    width: 200,
  }),
  singleValue: (provided, state) => {
    const opacity = state.isDisabled ? 0.5 : 1;
    const transition = 'opacity 300ms';

    return { ...provided, opacity, transition };
  }
}

const App = () => (
    <Select
      styles={customStyles}
      options={...}
    />
  );
```

Comment: What part of this changes the colour to grey?

Comment: Try changing ```color``` in the ```option``` key

Comment: I think thats the color of the options not the colour of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

React-select has a prop styles where you set an object that has a list of predefined properties for styling.
You can find more info here: https://react-select.com/styles
But to makes this more easy for you, in your situation you would write something like this.

```
<ReactSelect
    className='react-select react-select-top'
    classNamePrefix='react-select'
    id='displayLanguage'
    menuIsOpen={this.state.openMenu}
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    options={timeOptions}
    clearable={false}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
    value={this.state.selectedOption}
    onMenuClose={this.handleMenuClose}
    onMenuOpen={this.handleMenuOpen}
    aria-labelledby='changeInterfaceLanguageLabel'
    isDisabled={false}
    styles={{
        control: (styles) => ({
          ...styles,
          background: '#eee'
          })
        }}
/>
```

Comment: I'm using type script and I tried this but it did not change anything.

Comment: Using Typescript should not effect things in this situation. TypeScript is about using types and interfaces. Makes sure you are removing any strange css you added via className and you are using the correct property in styles, control should change the first box you see

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I tried the same thing but it did not work.